# How to determine the cause of GDB pretty printing issues?

Tags: gdb, pretty-print

I'm trying to determine why GDB on my system does not provide any pretty printing for C++ standard library types.

Command `info pretty-printer` yields some bogus output:

```
global pretty-printers:
  builtin
    mpx_bound128
Python Exception <type 'exceptions.UnicodeEncodeError'> 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 48-53: ordinal not in range(128): 
Error occurred in Python: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 48-53: ordinal not in range(128)
```

And I can't seem to find the offending gdbinit script.

Comment: Try `set python print-stack full` before the info command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to overcome the issue by altering the default Python encoding in `.gdbinit` script as follows:

```py
python
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
end
```